# add and remove dynamically a multiple datepickers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

The thing is when I add a new register, I need that all datepickers going destroy and bring live again all of them. I tried to add and remove dynamically a multiple datepicker, but I can't achieve.

```
$v = jQuery.noConflict();

function displayDatePickers(toogle){
    setDatePickers(toogle);
    setTimePickers(toogle);
}

function setDatePickers(toogle){
    if (toogle) {
            // toogle == true | destroy all datepickers
        $v(".datepicker").datepicker('destroy');
    }

    $v(".datepicker").datepicker();
}

function setTimePickers(toogle){
    if (toogle) {
            // toogle == true | destroy all datepickers
        $v('.timepicker').timepicker("destroy");
    }

    $v('.timepicker').timepicker({
    defaultTime: "Now"
    }); 
}
```

If someone can help me. Thanks.